# Python - How to read HTML line by line

Tags: python, html

I am trying to write a program that will take an HTML file and output each line. I am doing something wrong because my code is outputting each letter. How can I get all the HTML lines into a list?

This is the code so far:

```
f = open("/home/tony/Downloads/page1/test.html", "r")
htmltext = f.read()
f.close()

for t in htmltext:
    print t + "\n"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `f.readlines()` instead of `f.read()`. This function returns a list of all the lines in the file.

```
with open("/home/tony/Downloads/page1/test.html", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print(line)
```

Alternatively you could use `list(f)`.

```
f = open("/home/tony/Downloads/page1/test.html", "r")
f_lines = list(f)
for line in f_lines:
    print(line)
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Answer (score 1):

`f.read()` will attempt to read and yield each character until an EOF is met. What you want is the `f.readlines()` method:

```
with open("/home/tony/Downloads/page1/test.html", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print(line) # The newline is included in line
```